# open file with localhost server

Tags: windows, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a simple context menu item to open a file in my localhost server. I'm part of the way there, but what I can't seem to get working is to have it only use the filename itself instead of the entire file and path.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open as localhost]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open as localhost\command]
@="firefox.exe http://localhost/%1"
```

that loads `http://localhost/C:\wamp\www\myfile.html`

when I just want `http://localhost/myfile.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that gets passed always contains the full path. You need to create an intermediate sort of file opener, like a batch file, that removes the full path and only uses the file name.

**UPDATE**
To use a batch file, create a bat with this in it:

```
start http://localhost/%~n1%~x1
```

or

```
firefox http://localhost/%~n1%~x1
```

Then in your HKEY, execute the batch statement

```
@="firefox.exe file.bat %1"
```

It might work to just use the batch file selector in your HKEY, too:

```
@="firefox.exe http://localhost/%~n1%~x1
```

Comment: OK. Any idea how to do that? It's been years since I messed with .bat files

Comment: Actually, the selector for file only in a batch file might work - try `%~nI` instead of `%I`.

Comment: no dice on either. when implemented, it opens two windows, once with the same file path / name, the other trying to open www.file.bat

Comment: Had to tweak the setup a bit, but here's the working model.

The bat file: `start http://localhost/%~n1%~x1`
the reg file: `@="C:\localopen.bat %1"`

Comment: Good - I'd appreciate it if you'd mark the answer "correct" if it worked.